# How to find the day, month and year with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`2014-07-28`

How do I find the `month`, `year` and `day` with `moment.js` given the date format above?

```
var check = moment(n.entry.date_entered).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
var month = check.getUTCMonth();
var day = check.entry.date_entered.getUTCDate();
var year = check.entry.date_entered.getUTCFullYear();
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Just try with:

```
var check = moment(n.entry.date_entered, 'YYYY/MM/DD');

var month = check.format('M');
var day   = check.format('D');
var year  = check.format('YYYY');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5VLG/)

Comment: make a note that the values for all of them is a string not a number as someone you may expect

Comment: For this minus is that it converts values to strings.

Answer (score 159):

I know this has already been answered, but I stumbled across this question and went down the path of using `format`, which works, but it returns them as strings when I wanted integers.

I just realized that moment comes with `date`, `month` and `year` methods that return the actual integers for each method.

```
moment().date()
moment().month()  // jan=0, dec=11
moment().year()
```

Comment: its not .day() but .date() to get the current day of the month.

Comment: `month()` is zero based whereas `date()` is not. For many applications you'll want `moment().month() + 1`

Answer (score 30):

If you are looking for answer in string values , try this

```
var check = moment('date/utc format');
day = check.format('dddd') // => ('Monday' , 'Tuesday' ----)
month = check.format('MMMM') // => ('January','February.....)
year = check.format('YYYY') // => ('2012','2013' ...)
```

Answer (score 16):

I am getting `day`, `month` and `year` using dedicated functions [moment().date()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/), [moment().month()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) and [moment().year()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/) of `momentjs`.

```js
let day = moment('2014-07-28', 'YYYY/MM/DD').date();
let month = 1 + moment('2014-07-28', 'YYYY/MM/DD').month();
let year = moment('2014-07-28', 'YYYY/MM/DD').year();

console.log(day);
console.log(month);
console.log(year);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know why there are 48 upvotes for @Chris Schmitz answer which is not 100% correct.

Month is in form of array and starts from 0 so to get exact value we should use `1 + moment().month()`

Comment: you pass different format of the date than the format you defined. Different separators

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that you could use :

```
 var myDateVariable= moment("01/01/2019").format("dddd Do MMMM YYYY")
```

- dddd : Full day Name
- Do   : day of the Month
- MMMM : Full Month name
- YYYY : 4 digits Year

For more informations :

https://flaviocopes.com/momentjs/